# How to share code between 2 feature branches

Tags: git, merge, feature-branch

Let's say I've written a `method` in `feature1 branch` and after some time I realize that I need this piece of code in another `feature2 branch` as well.

So I just copy/paste the code from `feature1` into `feature2` and the work simultaneously continues on both branches. I cannot merge `feature1` into `feature2`, because then reviewers of `feature2` will also have to check the changes from `feature1` as well.
Then I ask reviewers to review both features.

Assume `feature1` is merged into master and then I want to merge `feature2` into master as well. But because of the copy/paste I get a merge conflict, so I have to ask for reviews again.
This is not a problem per se. But is there a way to avoid this conflict?

Comment: What does "At this point I can't cherry pick from feature1 since I was not aware of this need" mean? Can you elaborate?

Comment: `feature1 branch` is already merged to `master`,  so you should have `pulled` from master to your local branch  `feature2 branch` before pasting what you copied. Afterward you can push to your remote `feature2 branch` and then merge to `master`.

Comment: @RomainValeri I mean the shared method was not added in a single clean commit in feature1 so that the person on feature2 can pick it up

Comment: @OlasimboArigbabu All I'm saying is before both are merged. People are simultaneously working on these 2 branches

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question starts with some incorrect assumptions:

- You *can* cherry-pick, if you like.
- Cherry-picking itself does not mean that you *will* have conflicts.  It does not mean that you *won't* have conflicts either.
- You can indeed copy-paste some code; as before, this neither causes nor avoids conflicts on its own.
- Conflicts are not evil!  Well, you didn't say they were , but let's just make this clear:  All that a "conflict" means is that Git, when it attempted to combine work, was unable to complete this combining on its own.  That's not a tragedy and it's often very easy for a human to resolve.

Let's take a look at what it means to *merge* in Git, and some of the common things that go wrong.

#### Git is about commits

Those new to Git often think Git is about files or branches, but it's not.  Git is about *commits*.  A commit *holds* files—each commit has a full snapshot of *every* file, in fact—and we organize and find our commits *using* branches, so files and branches have a part.  But the heart and soul of Git is the commit.

Git stores these commits in a big database full of Git "objects".  There are four kinds of objects internally: *blob*, *tree*, *commit*, and *annotated tag* to be exact.  But for the most part, humans only deal with the commit objects.  These store our commits, and since the commit is the "unit of work" in a Git repository, as it were—because Git stores *commits*—that's the level at which we deal with Git.

Unfortunately for us humans, Git's commits are numbered, with big ugly random-looking numbers that have no rhyme or reason;<sup>1</sup> they look like [<sup>`1bcf4f6271ad8c952739164d160e97efd579424f`</sup>](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1bcf4f6271ad8c952739164d160e97efd579424f), for instance.  Humans can't deal with these, so we just don't.  Git provides for us by adding, separately from the big database of commits and other objects, a smaller database of *names*, including branch and tag names.  A name like `refs/heads/main` or `refs/heads/master` is a *branch* name and will turn into the big ugly hash ID *for* us.  So we can give Git a branch name, and Git will fish out the right hash ID, and use that to fish out the right commit.

That's how and why we can use names like `feature1` and `feature2`.  These names mean less than nothing to Git.  Git doesn't really need them, and does not care how we spell them or what we do with them—we can rename them whenever we like for instance—and just provides them for *us* to use so that *we* don't have to memorize hash IDs.  Git turns the names into hash IDs and finds the commits by their hash IDs and gets to work.  So Git isn't using your branch name at this time: it's only using the commit itself, which Git found by its hash ID.

This is how and why Git is all about the *commits*.  We use branch names, but Git mostly doesn't.  I say *mostly* because we're about to hit the point where Git *does* use branch names, to keep them up to date for us.

---

<sup>1</sup>Technically, they're just outputs from some cryptographic hash.  Traditionally, Git uses SHA-1, but Git now supports SHA-256.  There's ongoing work on making this more useful: for now, if you're a Git user as opposed to a Git developer, you'll just be using SHA-1.

---

#### What's in a commit

Remember that each commit in Git has one of those big ugly hash IDs.  These are *unique* to *that particular commit:* no other Git commit, anywhere, is *ever allowed to use that hash ID again*.<sup>2</sup>  So if we take any two Git repositories out on leashes to the Git-repository-park (like taking the dog to the dog park), they can go sniff each other and decide which commits one has that the other doesn't, just by looking at hash IDs.  Then one Git repository can get the other's commits, knowing that the first repository is missing those commits based on the hash ID alone.

We won't worry about this exchange-of-commits stuff here—that's the *distributed* part of Git being a distributed version control system—but it's important to keep this "unique hash ID" thing in mind as we look at what's inside any one given commit:

- Each commit has a *full snapshot of every source file, frozen for all time*.  If you have that commit, you have that snapshot.  (If you don't have that commit, you might still have that snapshot—two or more commits might have the *same* snapshot—but you can't tell for sure: you have to have the commit.)  The files in these snapshots are stored cleverly, with compression and *de-duplication*, so that the repository doesn't grow tremendously fat as we add new commits: most files are either total duplicates, or near-duplicates, of some earlier file, and this gets compressed down to nothing at all (a duplicate) or very little storage.  We'll skip all the details, even though they're mesmerizing.
- Meanwhile, each commit stores some *metadata*, or information about the commit itself.  This includes the name and email address of the author of the commit, for instance.

The metadata in any one commit aren't necessarily huge (or small—your commit log message goes here, so if you write a really big one, it's here, occupying that space).  But besides your name and email address, Git adds, to each commit, a *list of parent commit hash IDs*.  This list is usually exactly one entry long.

What this means is that given the *latest* commit, we can have Git work backwards to find the *second-latest* commit, all on its own.  Let's draw this.  Suppose the latest commit has some big ugly hash ID that we won't try to guess but will just call `H`, for "hash".  We'll draw it like this:

```
            <-H
```

Commit `H` has a little arrow sticking out of it, in our drawing.  In reality, commit `H` has a *hash ID* in its metadata, and that hash ID is the hash ID of the commit that comes *before* `H`.  Let's call that commit `G` and draw it in:

```
        <-G <-H
```

Of course, commit `G` is a commit, so it has a hash ID "arrow" like `H`'s.  Commit `G`'s arrow *points to* the commit that comes before `G`, which we'll call `F`:

```
... <-F <-G <-H
```

Commit `F` has an arrow that points to *its* parent, and so on.  So all we have to do, to have Git find *all* the commits, is somehow have Git find the *latest* commit `H`.

Well, we just said earlier that a *branch name* like `main` or `feature1` stores a hash ID.  So this name points to `H`, just like `H` points to `G`, and so on:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- main
```

One of the tricks that Git has to use, to keep the hash IDs working, is that all parts of *any* commit are frozen for all time.  That includes the hash IDs that point backwards to previous commits.  So `H` will *always* point to `G`, which will always point to `F`, and so on.  As such, I get to be a little lazy about drawing the arrows that connect commits to each other.

This is *not* the case for *branch names*.  The arrows in a branch name *move*.

---

<sup>2</sup>This constraint gets relaxed a bit in two Git repositories that never meet.  As long as they don't meet, the two separate Git repositories are allowed to accidentally re-use a hash ID.  This doesn't really happen in practice anyway, especially because it's humans who control which repositories eventually meet.  Git doesn't know what those crazy humans will do in the future, so Git just tries to ensure that every commit gets a totally unique hash ID.

---

#### Making a new commit

To make a new commit, we *check out* some branch with `git checkout`, or use `git switch` to "switch to" the branch, thus "checking it out", to the same effect.  Git remembers which *branch name* we used, by attaching the special name `HEAD` to one of the branch names in the repository.  At this particular point we only have one name, `main`, so there's not that much need for it, but we have this:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- main (HEAD)
```

Let's create a *new branch name* now though.  Let's create the name `feature1`.  This name *must point to some existing commit*.  We can pick any commit in the repository, but typically we'll pick the latest `main`-branch commit (or maybe the latest `develop`-branch commit or something, but for now we only have `main` anyway).  So the new name `feature1` will also point to commit `H`:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- feature1, main (HEAD)
```

Note how *all* the commits are on *both branches*.  Both names select commit `H` right now.  That's about to change, though.

We now use `git switch feature1` or `git checkout feature1` to select the *name* `feature1` with which to select commit `H`.  This changes our picture:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- feature1 (HEAD), main
```

We have not changed *commits*, so we are working with the same files, but we have changed which *branch name* we are using to find commit `H`.

Now we do our usual thing of modifying and `git add`-ing and `git commit`-ing.  When Git is done making the new commit, the new commit holds a new snapshot of all of the files (frozen, compressed, de-duplicated, and read-only), and the new commit—which we will call commit `I`—has commit `H` as its parent:

```
             I
            /
...--F--G--H
```

But—here's Git's little magic trick—Git has *stored `I`'s hash ID in the current branch*, the name to which `HEAD` is attached.  So if we include the branch names in the picture, we now have this:

```
             I   <-- feature1 (HEAD)
            /
...--F--G--H   <-- main
```

New commit `I` is only on `feature1` right now.  Commits up through `H` continue to be on both branches.  If we make another new commit `J`, we get:

```
             I--J   <-- feature1 (HEAD)
            /
...--F--G--H   <-- main
```

If we now `git switch main` or `git checkout main`, we get:

```
             I--J   <-- feature1
            /
...--F--G--H   <-- main (HEAD)
```

Git will remove, from our work area, the files from commit `J`, and put in place the files from commit `H` instead.  (We haven't covered the working tree and Git's index here, and for space reasons, we won't.)

Let's now make a second branch name, `feature2`, that *also* points to commit `H`, and then switch to `feature2`:

```
             I--J   <-- feature1
            /
...--F--G--H   <-- feature2 (HEAD), main
```

As we make new commits on `feature2`, they cause `feature2` to grow, just as happened with `feature`:

```
             I--J   <-- feature1
            /
...--F--G--H   <-- main
            \
             K--L   <-- feature2 (HEAD)
```

#### So that's a branch

This is really what branches, in Git, are about.  We call the *latest* commit, as found by some branch *name*, the *tip commit* of the branch.  (That's an official Git term.)  We call that commit plus some string of earlier commits "the branch", and we also call the name "the branch".  So when someone says "branch feature1", they might mean:

- the name `feature1`; or
- commit `J`, the tip commit of `feature1`; or
- commits `I-J`, which are only *on* `feature1` right now; or
- commits up through `J`, including `H` and other commits that are *also* on `main`;

or perhaps some other thing.  The word *branch*, in Git, is rather badly overused, and it's often a good idea to be more specific (you can say "branch name" or "tip commit" or "set of commits", for instance).

#### Merging

When we have *diverging* branches like the above—`feature1` and `feature2` diverge from commit `H` and end at commits `J` and `L` respectively—we often later want to *combine work*.  That is, given:

```
          I--J   <-- feature1
         /
...--G--H
         \
          K--L   <-- feature2
```

we'd like to get a single commit `M` that has, as its snapshot, a set of files that:

- are like the ones in `H`, except ...
- they have the changes we made in `I` and `J`, and
- they have the changes we made in `K` and `L` too.

We often achieve this in Git using `git merge`.

To run `git merge`, we:

- pick one of the two *tip commits*, usually by branch name, by checking out / switching to that branch name;
- run `git merge` and give it the other commit's hash ID, usually by branch name.

So we run `git switch feature1 && git merge feature2`, or maybe `git switch feature2 && git merge feature1`.

When we do this, Git will:

- locate the *current commit* (using `HEAD` and the branch name);
- locate the other commit (using the branch name we gave it); and
- find the *best shared commit:* a commit that is on *both branches*, whose snapshot Git can use as the common starting point.

Our goal, remember, is to *combine work*.  Commits, however, don't contain *work*.  They contain *snapshots:* complete archives of the entire source.

So, by finding a "best" *common starting point*—which in this case is obviously commit `H`—Git can simply compare the files *in* commit `H` with those *in* commit `J`, to see what *changed* on `feature1`.

The output of this comparison is a line-by-line set of changes to file-by-file changes for any *changed files* in the two commits.  Files that didn't change at all—that stayed the same from `H` to `J`—aren't mentioned.  That's what you'll see if you run `git diff` on commits `H` and `J`, and that's what `git merge` will see.

Having figured out which files changed, and what changed in them, from `H` to `J`, Git now runs the *same kind of comparison*, from commit `H` to commit `L`.  As before, this finds out which files were changed and what changed within those files, line-by-line.

The `git merge` command now *combines the changes*.  If "we" (`H`-vs-`J`, if we're on `feature1` now) touched some file and they (`H`-vs-`L`) didn't, Git keeps our changes.  If we didn't touch the file but they did, Git keeps their changes.  If we *both* touched the file, Git tries to *combine* our changes.

You get a *merge conflict* if and when we and they made *different changes* to the *same source lines*.  You also get a merge conflict if we and they touched two line ranges that "touch at the edges" ([abut](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/abut)).  **All this means is that Git is not sure about how to combine these changes.**  Your job as the programmer is to provide the *correct* combination.

That's what a merge conflict is about: Git isn't sure if taking the changes line-by-line is right.  If you *don't* get a merge conflict, Git *is* sure that taking the changes line-by-line is right, *even if it isn't actually right*.  Git is not smart here: Git is following ridiculously simple rules about text lines.

Once you fix the merge conflicts, or if Git has no merge conflicts, Git makes a new commit as usual.  The one thing that is special about this new commit `M` is that instead of just the one parent `J`, it has a *second* parent, `L`: the commit we said that Git should merge.  Git stores the new merge commit's hash ID into the current branch name as usual, so we get:

```
          I--J
         /    \
...--G--H      M   <-- feature1 (HEAD)
         \    /
          K--L   <-- feature2
```

Because commit `M` connects backwards to *both* commits `J` *and* `L`, commits `K-L`, which used to be only on `feature2`, are now on *both branches*.  Commits `I-J-M` are still only on `feature1` here because `L` is still the *tip* commit of `feature2`, and Git can only work backwards, not forwards.  So from `L` we go backwards to `K`, then `H`, then `G`, never seeing commits `I-J-M`.

#### Trivial merges

Sometimes we make merges that are *really easy* for Git:

```
          H--I   <-- feature
         /
...--F--G   <-- main
```

We run `git switch main` and then `git merge --no-ff feature` (the `--no-ff` is required to make this act like GitHub's "merge" button; it defeats a short-cut that Git normally takes here).  Git finds the common starting commit, but that's commit `G`, which is also the tip commit of `main`.  So a full merge consists of:

- compare the snapshot in `G` against the snapshot in `G` to see what changed (nothing);
- compare the snapshot in `G` against the one in `I` to see what changed;
- add nothing to what-changed, getting what-changed;
- apply those changes to `G`, getting the *same snapshot that is in `I` already;* and
- make a new commit and update the current branch name.

The result looks like this:

```
          H--I   <-- feature
         /    \
...--F--G------M   <-- main (HEAD)
```

(I called the merge commit `M` again, for Merge; in reality it gets a unique hash ID, like every commit.)  The snapshot in `M` is guaranteed to match the snapshot in `I`, because `G`-vs-`G` never has any changes to add, while `G`-vs-`I` always has the changes to add that result in the `I` snapshot.

If we don't prevent Git from doing so, Git will turn this trivial merge into a *fast-forward* operation, which isn't really a merge at all.  Instead of a new commit, we just get this:

```
          H--I   <-- feature, main (HEAD)
         /
...--F--G
```

That is, Git just scoots the name `main` forward two hops, like fast-forwarding a [tape recorder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tape_recorder).  It's literally just a checkout that drags the name—in this case, `main`—forward.  Git swaps out the commit-`G` files in our working tree for the commit-`I` files.  No merge is needed, so no merge happens; no merge conflict *can* happen, so no merge is needed.

Force the merge with `--no-ff` (no fast forward) and the merge happens and you get a new merge commit.  Sometimes you want this (for release tagging purposes for instance) and sometimes you don't care.  To know whether you want it, you need to know that Git is all about *commits*.  A new commit gets a new, unique hash ID, which we can tell apart from every other commit.  "Re-use" a commit like fast-forward does and we *don't* get a new commit and therefore it's the same old commit as before.

#### Cherry-picking

Suppose we have:

```
          I--J--K   <-- br1
         /
...--G--H
         \
          L   <-- br2 (HEAD)
```

We suddenly realize that commit `J`, say, fixed a nasty bug that we *need to be fixed* in `br2`.  We could copy and paste the code changes from that commit, but if that commit *exactly fixes* the bug, it would be nice if we could get Git to *compare the commit before that commit—commit `I`—to that commit to see *what changed*.  That is, we'd like Git to diff the snapshots in `I` and `J` to see which files had what changes made.

Given that Git can do that easily, we have Git do it.  Then we have Git apply those same changes to our current versions of those files in commit `L`.  We *could* have Git just literally make the same changes to the same lines, but what happens if, say, the fix for `thing.py` is on line 45 in *their* version, but we added a new function near the top and the fix goes on line 70 in *our* version of `thing.py`?

Well, we can have Git apply the fix a lot more cleverly.  If we have Git diff commit `I`'s version of `thing.py` against commit `L`'s version of `thing.py`, that will show our added function, and that what was line 45 is now line 70.  So Git will be able to apply *their* change to line 70, which is the correct line.

But hang on a minute.  We're having Git *compare the file in snapshot `I`* to *the file in snapshot `J`* and also to *the file in snapshot `L`*.  What were we doing a moment ago with `git merge`?  **We were doing the exact same thing with `git merge`.**  Merge compares snapshots and *combines changes*.

That's exactly how cherry-pick works: it's literally a merge operation, with the merge base being forced.  We're cherry-picking from commit `J`.  Commit `J`'s parent is commit `I`.  So Git uses commit `I` as the *merge base*, commit `J` as "their" branch-tip commit, and our current commit `L` as "our" commit.  Git makes the usual diffs, and then combines work as usual.  The thing that's *not* like a merge is that, once Git is done with the combining-work part, Git makes an *ordinary* (non-merge) commit:

```
          I--J--K   <-- br1
         /
...--G--H
         \
          L--N   <-- br2 (HEAD)
```

New commit `N` will make the same *changes* to `L` that `J`-vs-`I` made to `I`, adjusted as necessary.  The cherry-pick code uses the *merge engine* to achieve the "adjusted as necessary" part.

Cherry-picking can therefore get merge conflicts during the cherry-pick operation!  That's normal, and as with `git merge` it is nothing to be afraid of: you, as the programmer, merely need to supply the *correct result*.  Whatever you tell Git is the correct result, Git will believe you: that's what goes into the new commit's snapshot.

If you had to modify the code when you cherry-picked it, it's very likely that you'll get a merge conflict later if you merge `N` and `L`, for instance.  That's because we took a change (to some set of lines) and *modified the change*, so later, when Git goes to combine changes, it will see slightly different changes that affect the "same lines", as it were.  We'll have to resolve another merge conflict later.  There's no guarantee that we won't have to resolve a merge conflict later even if this *doesn't* happen, though.  Mostly, we just let the merge conflicts happen as they do, and fix them up manually.  That's part of the job of being a programmer.